# css3 design tutorial/template etc

Tags: css

I search some tutorial/templates how made easy (lightwight) and nice css3 design, or made with some "css framework" etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good resources for CSS templates or templated layout sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522856/what-are-good-resources-for-css-templates-or-templated-layout-sites)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a pure CSS3 layout template, what you will find is a layout with CSS3 features added in. I would suggest using a CSS2 template then look to see which CSS3 features you can utilize in it. Remember, CSS3 is not fully compatible with IE8.

Smashing Magainze has some great resources for CSS3 features.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/take-your-design-to-the-next-level-with-css3/